# duplicate insert after refresh page (iam new in developing with codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

i need to stop insert data when refresh page iam new in codeigniter and can't do redirect easly,please support 
view:pages/home.php view which has a form

```
<html>
<head></head>
</body>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('speed/insert_to_db'); ?>

Branch: <input type="text" name="branch" /><br/>
Business Unit: <input type="text" name="buinessUnit" /><br/>
Device Type: <input type="text" name="deviceType" /><br/>
Brand: <input type="text" name="brand" /><br/>
Device Model: <input type="text" name="deviceModel" /><br/>
SN: <input type="text" name="SN" /><br/>
status: <input type="text" name="status" /><br/>
department: <input type="text" name="department" /><br/>
username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
notes: <input type="textarea" name="notes" /><br/>
computername: <input type="text" name="computerName" /><br/>
Save:<input type="submit" name="save" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

model:add_model model which has insert_to_db function

```
       public function insert_into_db(){
           $post=$this->input->post();

           $data=array('Branch'=>$post['branch'],'BusinessUnit'=>$post['buinessUnit'],'DeviceType'=>$post['deviceType'],'Brand'=>$post['brand'],'DeviceModel'=>$post['deviceModel'],'SN'=>$post['SN'],'Status'=>$post['status'],'Departmant'=>$post['department'],'UserName'=>$post['username'],'Notes'=>$post['notes'],'ComputerName'=>$post['computerName']);
           $this->db->insert('hardware_assets', $data);
return $this->db->insert_id(); // if using mysql
       }
}
```

controller:

```
<?php

class Speed extends CI_Controller {

        function insert_to_db()
           {

             $this->load->model('add_model');
             if($this->input->post('save')){
             $this->add_model->insert_into_db();
             $this->load->view('pages/home');//loading success view
             }
           }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this in your controler:

```
function insert_to_db()
{
   $this->load->model('add_model');

   if( isset( $this->input->post('save') ) )
   {
      $this->add_model->insert_into_db();

      //loading success view
      $this->load->view('pages/home');
   }
}
```

Comment: it return with error Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in C:\wamp\www\speed\application\controllers\speed.php on line 9

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html try this documentation it will tell you how to verify that form is submitted successfully or not and then add the data to database